# Entity How to allow ForeignKey in parent child relationship?

Tags: entity-framework-5

I have Entity

```
/// <summary>
/// The greoup.
/// </summary>
public class Group
{
    #region Public Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the group id.
    /// </summary>
    [Key]
    public int GroupId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the parent group id.
    /// </summary>     
    public int ParentGroupId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the active.
    /// </summary>
    public int Active { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the description.
    /// </summary>
    public string Description { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the group guid.
    /// </summary>
    public Guid GroupGuid { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the order weight.
    /// </summary>
    public int OrderWeight { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the parent group.
    /// </summary>
    [ForeignKey("ParentGroupId")]
    public virtual Group ParentGroup { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the groups.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual ICollection<Group> Groups { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

How I can to allow exited foreign key. Because when I try add Group when ParentGroupId = 0. I get exception

> Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations. Dependencies may exist due to foreign key constraints, model requirements, or store-generated values.

Comment: What do you mean by "exited foreign key"? Is GroupId an identity column? Can you show code that raises the exception?

Answer (score 0):

you are creating a self referencing table in the database with this structure. So the `ParentGroupId` must be nullable. The root node cannot have a parent , all the nodes arising from it will however have a parent, so you need to make the `ParentGroupId` nullable.

Comment: No. Root ParentGroupId must be to 0

Comment: As per your code each node must have a parent , then the root must also have a parent which is not possible since the root does not have a parent. Hence the need for it to be nullable.